# Elixir/Erlang - Split paragraph into sentences based on the language

Tags: parsing, split, nlp, erlang, elixir

In Java there is a class called BreakItterator which allows me to pass a paragraph of text in any language (the language it is written in is known) and it will split the text into separate sentences. The magic is that it can take as an argument the locale of the langue the text is written in and it will split the text according to that languages rules (if you look into it it is actually a very complex issue even in English - it is certainly not a case of 'split by full-stops/periods').

Does anybody know how I would do this in elixir? I can't find anything in a Google search.

I am almost at the point of deploying a very thin public API that does only this basic task that I can call into from elixir - but this is really not desirable.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I doubt you'll find an equivalent library function in Elixir.  A way forward might be to convert the code from https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/text/BreakIterator.java

Comment: Thanks for the info :) I had considered converting the Java code. I may have to do that. Or even just look into using clojure maybe.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff Not in the standard library, but there are third-party libraries for this.

Comment: I have looked at third party solutions but to be honest the most promising one I saw had been abandoned 2 or more years ago. I am happy to use the erlang module suggested. Cheers for your input and time chaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[i18n](https://github.com/erlang-unicode/i18n) library should be usable for this. Just going from the examples provided, since I have no experience using it, something like the following should work (`:en` is the locale code):

```
str = :i18n_string.from("some string")
iter = :i18n_iterator.open(:en, :sentence)
sentences = :i18n_string.split(iter, str)
```

There's also [Cldr](https://github.com/elixir-cldr/cldr), which implements a lot of locale-dependent Unicode algorithms directly in Elixir, but it doesn't seem to include iteration in particular at the moment (you may want to raise an issue there).

Comment: Ahh, i18n! Internationalization is the keyword I have been missing in my Google searches. 
Thanks so much!! :D I was really sad about the idea of compromising my language choice for this app, and now I don't think I'll need to. I am fairly new to elkixir but I am loving it.

Comment: I found it by searching for ICU instead, but you need to know about that library first :)

Comment: I see. yeah, it's often the way :)